# jQuery / Javascript Parallax Code - explanation

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I am following a tutorial for a basic parallax scrolling effect:

http://callmenick.com/2014/09/08/advanced-parallax-scrolling-effect/

It is a good tute and pretty easy to understand and implement but I came across some code I just can't quite get my head around.

```
(function(){

  var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
      speed = 0.5;

  window.onscroll = function(){
    [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){

      var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
          elBackgrounPos = "50% " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";

      el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;

    });
  };

})();
```

I get that it loops through all elements with the class parallax, gets the Yoffset and sets the background position. But can anyone breakdown this line with an explanation?

```
[].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i)
```

**UPDATE**

Some great explanations below but is this a better solution than using jQuery like so:

```
$('.parallax').each(function(){
        $this= $(this);
        var window_y = (window.pageYOffset+1000);
        var elBackgrounPos = "0 " + (window_y * speed) + "px";  
        $this.css('background-position', elBackgrounPos);
});
```

To me this is much more readable, but does the javascript version perform better or is more efficient in some ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, which is a special kind of DOM object. By using `call()`, we can invoke the `slice()` method of Javascript arrays to split the NodeList into something that allows us to then use the `forEach` method, which is not available on NodeLists.

Try this out in the Javascript console of your browser:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('div')
a.forEach

b = [].slice.call(a)
b.forEach
```

You'll see that a.forEach will return `undefined` and b.forEach will return

`function forEach() { [native code] }`

Basically it lets us manipulate the NodeList items in an easier way. You'll also see that the `__proto__` property of b is `[]` while the `__proto__` property of a is `NodeList`. This is why b can call `forEach` and a cannot.

Comment: Really good, thanks. Do you think this is a better solution than the jQuery alternative I've added?

Comment: If you're already using jQuery in your project, and you feel more comfortable with the syntax, definitely use the jQuery option. Otherwise, if this is all you'd be using jQuery for, vanilla javascript would probably be best since its easily accomplished without having to load jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

The parallax object is of the type [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which doesn't have a forEach method.

However using JavaScript's call(), which exists on all objects, we can temporarily give it the ability to use forEach as if it were an array.

you could even shorten the code to be just `[].forEach.call(parallax, function(el, i) {...})`

[call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and apply() are methods you should definitely check out if you're not familiar with them